# How do spiders get silk from their spinnerettes?

Tags: zoology, proteins, homework, arthropod

I'm 13 and writing a report on spiders. How do they use the silk protein gel from the spinnerets? How does it get from the spinnerets to the web? P.S. I know how silk is created, all the way up until the tapering duct

As I currently understand it, the silk proteins are created, then dissolved into a liquid/gel, and stored. Then it is put through a funnel into the tapering duct, liquid is removed. I'm missing an understanding between the removal of the liquid and formation of the silk. Could someone fill in the gap?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. There is an expectation that you [research your question before asking it here.](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) Updating your question to include details of your own research will help people to provide specific answers. It will also ensure your question isn't downvoted or closed for being a [homework question.](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)

Comment: A: This isn't homework because I'm homeschooled (just to clarify.)

Comment: B: My dad tried to install security software and search engines are down. I can only use websites I've been to. Although I do know that silk proteins are created, then dissolved into a liquid/gel, and stored. Then it is put through a funnel into the tapering duct, liquid is removed..... And then I don't know what happens with it......

Comment: The link in my initial comment outlines the homework policy, which is broad enough to include your question. You can ask homework questions here but you need to show that you have researched the question. The following quote from your comment satisfies that criteria and it you should add it to your question; `Silk proteins are created, then dissolved into a liquid/gel, and stored. Then it is put through a funnel into the tapering duct, liquid is removed..... And then I don't know what happens with it`

Comment: The term "homework question" is used as an umbrella term for the whole bunch of things like: Homework questions, assignments, low effort questions, not researched questions and so on. And your questions clearly falls under it at the moment, so please edit it accordingly.

Comment: As we actually have a homework tag we should not be to fast saying homework questions are off topic. This question has an open answer which could be interesting in other contexts than homework, it just needs more clarification. It is not too broad and definitely answerable by someone knowing more about spiders than I do.

Comment: @skymningen They are not off-topic when the person asking shows some effort to solve this by themselves. This varies of course between a 15 year old and a student of an university.

Comment: @Indigo2003 Your question has been edited to avoid deletion. You may further edit according to your needs. Besides here's a link, I would suggest you to go through before you post another homework question. biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework

Comment: I've seen earlier that exam-questions/ book-exercise questions or any-such type of evaluation-questions (which are usually not fundamental questions) considered as homework question.

Comment: I think if a spider expert sees this they will know exactly how to answer it. I urge other closure reviewers to leave the question open. Good luck with the report!